# Sorting dataframe by multiple columns through list of column names

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, vector

I have a loop, where in the different iterations I want to sort the dataframe using different column lists. I can do this sorting when I hardcode the sorting variables. However I want to pass the column names using variable list. I could not find a way of doing this.

```
DT <-data.frame(avar = c(1,4,3,1), bvar = c("a","f","s","b"), cvar = c(3,4,5,2))

sort1 <-c("avar", "cvar")
sort2 <-c("avar", "bvar")
sorting <-list(sort1,sort2)
DT2<-list()

for (i in 1:2) {
  sorter<- sorting[[i]]
   #THE FOLLOWING SOLUTION WORKS!!!
   DT2[[i]] <- DT[do.call(order,DT[as.character(sorting[[i]])]),]       
}
```

What I mean by sorting by c("avar", "cvar") is that the data is to be sorted by avar first, and (if there are two values of avar that are the same) then by cvar. In other words, the output of sorting by that vector should be only one sorted dataframe (not a list). Same thing about sorting by c("avar", "bvar"). Above "ps1" stands for one of the proposed solutions. It gives me DT2[[1]] that is a list of two dataframes. that is not what I need. DT2 should be a list of two dataframes. DT2[[1]] should be one dataframe.

I want to also stress that I do need this sorting to happen through a loop, not through passing the list ("sorting") to the command. In other words, first iteration should sort the database by first item of the sorting list, which is the vector "sorter" in my code. In real application, the data in different iterations is not the same dataset.

After the first loop, DT2[[1]] should be sorted as follows:

```
avar  bvar  cvar
1     b     2
1     a     3
3     s     5
4     f     4
```

after the second loop DT2[[2]] should be sorted as :

```
avar  bvar  cvar
1     a     3
1     b     2
3     s     5
4     f     4
```

In real life I may also have a different number of sorting columns in different iteration.

Regarding solutions proposed that use "map" function: I have some geospacial packages loaded (mapproj, fiftystater, geofacet), so the "map" function does not work as suggested unless I unload those packages. Is there a way to qualify to use native "map" function rather than geospacial map function?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The sample code you give is not valid R code. For example `sorting <-(sort1,sort2)` will throw an error. Ditto for `for (i = 1:2)`. This may suggest that there are deeper issues with general R syntax. Perhaps you need to take a step back and familiarise yourself with the basics of R first; you can find a lot of free material on the web. A good starting point could be [An introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the syntax in the post.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected that too. This is a much simplified version of 5000 line code. sorry for typos.

Comment: *"Is there a way to qualify to use native "map" function rather than geospacial map function?"* Just prefix with `purrr::map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The following solution works for me! Other proposed solutions I tried failed to sort by two variables in a given vector simultaneously.

DT <-data.frame(avar = c(1,4,3,1), bvar = c("a","f","s","b"), cvar = c(3,4,5,2))

sort1 <-c("avar", "cvar")
sort2 <-c("avar", "bvar")
sorting <-list(sort1,sort2)
DT2<-list()

for (i in 1:2) {
    #THE FOLLOWING SOLUTION WORKS!!!
    DT2[[i]] <- DT[do.call(order,DT[as.character(sorting[[i]])]),]       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R we can apply `order` on selected columns in `sorting` using `do.call`. We use `lapply` to get list of dataframes

```
lapply(sorting, function(x) DT[do.call(order, DT[x]), ])


#[[1]]
#  avar bvar cvar
#4    1    b    2
#1    1    a    3
#3    3    s    5
#2    4    f    4

#[[2]]
#  avar bvar cvar
#1    1    a    3
#4    1    b    2
#3    3    s    5
#2    4    f    4
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my original post (adding last three paragraphs) on why proposed solutions do not work.

Comment: @Edith I haven't used any `map` function in my answer but for remaining of them you could do `packageName::functionName` to use those package explicitly. For example, `purrr::map`

Comment: When I use your solution (  lapply(sorting[[1]], function(x) DT[do.call(order, DT[x]), ]), I get an output that is a list: first item is data sorted by avar, and the second item is data sorted by cvar. The second paragraph in my edited post explains what I want to happen instead.

Comment: @Edith I get the same expected output as shown in your post. `DT2 <- lapply(sorting, function(x) DT[do.call(order, DT[x]), ])`. `DT2[[1]]` and `DT[[2]]` are the two dataframes same as shown.

Comment: When I use our solution, DT2[[1]] is a list of two items - date sorted by avar and cvar respectively. I will edit the code to show exactly how I added that line.

Comment: @Edith you don't need a `for` loop here. If you use my solution as it is , you'll notice that `DT2[[1]]` is one dataframe sorted by `sorting[[1]]` and `DT2[[2]]` is another dataframe sorted by `sorting[[2]]` and as far as I can tell after reading your post that is what you need.

Comment: Thank you. In this simplified setting a command could give the same result as a loop, but in the real code the dataset in each iteration is not the same dataset. They are different datasets with different number of records and columns. So I really need to have a solution that works through a loop. Also, your solution does not give me DT2[[1]] as a dataframe. it gives me DT2[[1]] that is a list of two dataframes, and DT2[[2]] that is also a  list of two dataframes. You can see in the code from the post exactly how I have it. Please feel free to correct if wrong.

Comment: @Edith as I mentioned earlier you don't need to use a `for` loop to apply this solution. If you apply the `lapply` solution in a `for` loop you will get wrong results. Can you just do `DT2 <- lapply(sorting, function(x) DT[do.call(order, DT[x]), ])`  ?

Comment: (1) No, I can not. I absolutely can not do it outside the loop. In first iteration of the loop, DT has 11000 rows and 23 columns. In second iteration it has 202 rows and 22 columns. Even though it has the same name, it is not the same dataset. (2) If I do your solution outside the loop, like this: DT2 <- lapply(sorting, function(x) DT[do.call(order, DT[x]), ]), I get DT2 that is a list of 2 items. each item is a list of 2 dataframes. So I get 4 dataframes. That is not what I need. I do not think this is environment specific either - but happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr`+`purrr` solution

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(sorting, ~arrange(DT, !!!syms(.x)))
#[[1]]
#  avar bvar cvar
#1    1    b    2
#2    1    a    3
#3    3    s    5
#4    4    f    4
#
#[[2]]
#  avar bvar cvar
#1    1    a    3
#2    1    b    2
#3    3    s    5
#4    4    f    4
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my original post (adding last three paragraphs) on why proposed solutions do not work.

Comment: @Edit Use `purrr::map` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method with `setorder` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
Map(setorderv, replicate(2, copy(DT), simplify = FALSE), sorting)
#[[1]]
#  avar bvar cvar
#4    1    b    2
#1    1    a    3
#3    3    s    5
#2    4    f    4

#[[2]]
#  avar bvar cvar
#1    1    a    3
#4    1    b    2
#3    3    s    5
#2    4    f    4
```

---

Or use `arrange_at` from `dplyr` (without using the evaluation way)

```
library(tidyverse)
map(sorting, ~ DT %>%
                 arrange_at(.x))
#[[1]]
#  avar bvar cvar
#1    1    b    2
#2    1    a    3
#3    3    s    5
#4    4    f    4

#[[2]]
#  avar bvar cvar
#1    1    a    3
#2    1    b    2
#3    3    s    5
#4    4    f    4
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have two problems related to this solution:

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have two problems related to this solution: (1) I have some geospacial packages loaded as well (fifitystater, geofacet, mapproj). So it looks like "map" function from these packages "takes" over the native R map function. I get an error message on "map"statement unless I unload those geospecial packages. Is there a way to qualify to use native map function rather than what comes in geospacial tools.

Comment: Problem (2) Is more directly related to this issue. When I say to sort by c("avar", "bvar"), I do not want two separate outputs. I want the file to be sorted first by avar, and then (if there are two or more values of avar that are the same) by bvar. At the moment, using this proposed solution, I get the output that is a list: first item is data sorted by a. and the second item is data sorted by b.

Comment: @Edith Use `purrr::map(sorting, ~ DT %>%` to sort out the issue